# Run length Encoding for a given String

Tags: python-3.x

Given a string of upper case alphabets and we have to compress the string using Run length Encoding.
Input =  "AABBBACCDA"
output = 2A3B1A2C1D1A

Comment: You want us to solve it for you?

Comment: Specific problems and questions are welcome here, but people dumping their homework here are not. Voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: Yes...that would be big help..I'm not dumping my homework sir..I've been trying this question for a long time.. I am new to programming.. that's why I need some help

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) makes this pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's your homework I'm not going to solve it for you. The pythonic way would be to use some "magic" function that will solve your problem.

However you're here to learn programming in general, so implement this:
Count the characters until the next character is different from the current one.
Append to your output string the number the current character showed up and the current character.
Print.

Comment: Magic function huh... thanks for the logic...this idea Never crossed my mind :-/